# add additional mysql master

Tags: linux, mysql, replication, master-slave

I currently have 2 mysql servers running,
1 as master and 1 as slave as in the mysql manual
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html

master->slave

What I want to do is add a new mysql master to the current setup, so it does

master<->master->slave

Can anyone point me to any tutorials or howtos for doing it?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is essentially [Circular Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-replication-multi-master.html) (with a very small circle).